# [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, post, axios, next.js

error - Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
at NodeNextResponse.setHeader (E:\EndGame\FoodMart-client-side\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-http.js:101:19)
at DevServer.renderError (E:\EndGame\FoodMart-client-side\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1094:17)
at DevServer.renderError (E:\EndGame\FoodMart-client-side\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:414:22)
at DevServer.run (E:\EndGame\FoodMart-client-side\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:451:35)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async DevServer.handleRequest (E:\EndGame\FoodMart-client-side\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:305:20) {
code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}[image]

i can not understand from where the erron come in terminal but live site is okk.

Comment: Please include the actual code snippet that is causing this error and format/shorten the error to make it readable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your Next.js application, check your pages/api/preview.js file.  There is some code there that needs to be correct before the redirect will work

```
  export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.setPreviewData({}) 
  res.redirect(req.query.redirect)
}
```

if you have something like the following your code won't work

```
 res.end('Preview mode enabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using express. Somewhere in the code, you send the response after another response is sent. Make sure that you return the function after you call a res.send. All your res.send should have a return: `return rsp.send({});`